# How to implement share app or rate app or logout functionality in new navigation drawer architecture component

Tags: java, android, navigation, share, drawer

I am following the navigation architecture component guide from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

I want to add share app, rate app and sign out items in the navigation drawer like this[image]

I am able to link **Services, My Account** menus to their destination fragments but the problem is for the rate/share/sign out thing we don't need any special fragment/destination, right?. As NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController); this line does all the drawer item click event itself I cannot do much.

Still, I tried this way but it is not working

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.startup.housebuddy.R;
import com.startup.housebuddy.Utility.Utility;

public class ServiceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private TextView headerSubTitleTv;
    private TextView headerTitleTv;
    private NavController navController;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_service_list);

       // headerTitleTv = headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_title_tv);
        headerSubTitleTv = headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_subtitle);

        populateUpNavHeader();

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    /*    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();*/
        /*TODO : Add other ids of fragments required to show in navigation drawer*/
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_myAccount,R.id.nav_about)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
         navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        //NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }



     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.service_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
     {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            Utility.showToast("nav home", this);
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home);
            break;

        case R.id.nav_myAccount:
            Utility.showToast("nav accout", this);
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_myAccount);

            break;

        case R.id.nav_share:
            // do share intent
            Utility.showToast("Share", this);
            drawer.closeDrawers(); // close nav bar
            break;


    }
    drawer.closeDrawers(); // close nav bar
    return true;
}
    }
```

So my question is how can I implement these types of functionality for which no explicit destinations not required in navigation drawer?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear. But if you don't need a fragment to open just write the required logic inside if else condition. and close navigation bar

```
if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_share){

// do share intent

mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // close nav bar

}
else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.log_out){ 

    // write logic for log out
 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // close nav bar
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Hi @mehul Please check my updated code. It is working but just one problem is now suppose I am on service fragment itself and try to click on service again from drawer it is not loading recyclerview data. I debugged app but it is somehow not going in getItemCount() method of adapter even though there is data available. Please help! Thank you so much.

Comment: service fragment shows the list of services and refer above screenshot. Also when I navigate to suppose my account and then service it is showing the list in recyclerview. I am kinda confused why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's not possible to handle it in a lovely way. As always it's working not in all cases. As you probably try it's pointless to have those two methods.

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

For know I propose:

```
private fun setupNavigation() {
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navFragment.navController, drawerLayout)
    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}


override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.share_app -> navigator.shareApp(this) // some ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
        else -> navFragment.navController.navigate(item.itemId)
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```